# How to generate HTML for syntax highlighted code?

Tags: pastebin, syntax-highlighting

I want to post on my blog some syntax highlighted code. Sites like PasteBin allows you to do this, but they don't provide the HTML code hassle-free.

Instead they suggest you to embed tags like this:

```
<script src="http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=5GmRZ18V"></script>
```

Which are converted into the desired HTML at runtime.

Is there any such tool that exports the HTML for pasting on my blog (without javascript nor iframes)?

Comment: Do the html styles need to be inline (e.g. `<span style="font-weight:bold; color:blue">i</span>`) or is importing/creating a stylesheet fine (e.g. `<span class="variable">i</span>`)?

Comment: @Senseful importing a stylesheet is fine

Answer (score 1):

If you use windows live writer for your blog then there is a plugin available. More info

http://lvildosola.blogspot.com/2007/02/code-snippet-plugin-for-windows-live.html

If you don't you could add the additional style sheet to your site and just use the plugin for formatting before pasting into a post (just use wlw :P)